# Differences between snort and snort_inline

Tags: linux, skype, snort

I am using "snort_inline" and I forwarded all the packets using 
iptables to the QUEUE so that snort_inline can pick them up for 
inspection and drop/alert depending on the rules. 
But does "Snort" when run in inline mode take in packets from iptables 
too? What is the difference between Snort and Snort_inline when it 
comes to blocking packets ? 
I observe that when I run "Snort" without using iptables, somehow my 
packets are getting dropped. 
Would be helpful if someone clarifies this for me. 
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

snort_inline is depreciated and you should use Snort with DAQ.  Snort with DAQ can handle the same Snort "dropping" of packets.

There are several different inline modes that DAQ will support, iptables (nfqueue) being one of them.